# Android 8 native crash at libhwui.so

Tags: android, crash, android-8.0-oreo

Since the rollout of Android 8 Oreo, our app has been consistently crashing in different places. All the play store crash reports show native crashes. The most frequently occuring one seems to be at libhwui.so

The most frequent device that crashes is the Nexus 6P. Pixel and Pixel XL have also shown a few.

I ll post the crash log below. I m struggling to find what causes the crash.

Any help is appreciated.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/angler/angler:8.0.0/OPR6.170623.013/4283548:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 12908, tid: 12908, name: ***.***  >>> com.***.***.*** <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x100103
    x0   0000000000100103  x1   0000000000000000  x2   0000007f23be8000  x3   0000000000000000
    x4   0000000013305004  x5   00000000000000a8  x6   0000007f43d58000  x7   0000000000000000
    x8   0000000000000000  x9   0000000000000001  x10  0000000000000019  x11  0000000000000004
    x12  0000000000000000  x13  0000000000000008  x14  00000000000003e8  x15  0000000000000010
    x16  0000007f420e7a18  x17  0000007f3fd64fb4  x18  0000000000000020  x19  0000000000000000
    x20  0000007f23be8000  x21  00000000132ed218  x22  00000000132ece00  x23  0000000000000001
    x24  00000000132ed218  x25  0000000000000000  x26  00000000132eba68  x27  00000000132eddd8
    x28  0000000012f264d8  x29  0000007fe5077050  x30  00000000719d7ff4
    sp   0000007fe5077040  pc   0000007f3fd64fe4  pstate 0000000060000000

backtrace:
    #00 pc 000000000008bfe4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer10RenderNode21setStagingDisplayListEPNS0_11DisplayListE+48)
    #01 pc 0000000000ba1ff0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.nAddChild [DEDUPED]+160)
    #02 pc 0000000001334cb4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.view.RenderNode.discardDisplayList+52)
    #03 pc 00000000012bfe40  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.view.View.onDetachedFromWindowInternal+464)
    #04 pc 00000000012ad284  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow+196)
    #05 pc 000000000130de08  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow+248)
    #06 pc 0000000001378de8  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow+168)
    #07 pc 000000000137a240  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie+208)
    #08 pc 0000000001378828  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.die+72)
    #09 pc 00000000013928a0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked+320)
    #10 pc 0000000001394e54  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView+308)
    #11 pc 0000000001396438  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate+72)
    #12 pc 00000000006a9860  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity+320)
    #13 pc 000000000069fbe4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5+52)
    #14 pc 000000000069b3b0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+7088)
    #15 pc 000000000069745c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+188)
    #16 pc 0000000000f69fb0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.os.Looper.loop+1184)
    #17 pc 00000000006b1868  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (android.app.ActivityThread.main+904)
    #18 pc 000000000050ea38  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+600)
    #19 pc 00000000000d8110  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+268)
    #20 pc 0000000000436994  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+104)
    #21 pc 0000000000438504  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art12InvokeMethodERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectS4_S4_m+1464)
    #22 pc 00000000003c18d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL13Method_invokeEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectS3_S3_+48)
    #23 pc 0000000000266f74  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x1db000) (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+180)
    #24 pc 0000000001693ac8  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+136)
    #25 pc 00000000016978d4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5ea000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2884)
    #26 pc 000000000050ea38  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+600)
    #27 pc 00000000000d8110  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+268)
    #28 pc 0000000000436994  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+104)
    #29 pc 00000000004365e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17InvokeWithVarArgsERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+416)
    #30 pc 000000000034b848  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI21CallStaticVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+616)
    #31 pc 00000000000b4188  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7_JNIEnv20CallStaticVoidMethodEP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDz+120)
    #32 pc 00000000000b6248  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime5startEPKcRKNS_6VectorINS_7String8EEEb+824)
    #33 pc 0000000000002454  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1348)
    #34 pc 000000000001b668  /system/lib64/libc.so (__libc_init+88)
    #35 pc 0000000000001e70  /system/bin/app_process64 (do_arm64_start+80)
```